# VW T4: Which spare bulbs do I need to carry with me?

Tags: vw, lights

In some European countries, such as Croatia, you're required to carry a set of spare bulbs for all lights required by law with you.

Since I'm not that much into cars, I'm really unsure what spare bulbs I exactly need for my VW T4. Does this mean I need a spare bulb for both headlights, both back lights, both hazard lights, both break lights and the fog light? If so, how do I find out which spare lamb bulbs do fit into it?

Answer (score 1):

Most automotive suppliers should be able to tell you which bulbs you need. If you're in the UK, Halfords have a book on each shelf listing most major cars and the parts required, and they used to (I don't know if they still do) sell complete bulb kits for some cars - consisting of all the bulbs you'd need in a single plastic box.

Generally, the headlights are the same, all four main indicators are the same, and the tail-lights on both sides are the same - so you'd only need one of each, although you might prefer to have two for safety (after all, if one fails, and you use the spare, you then wouldn't have another...)